# I have a SQL table with multiple rows that I want into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a SQL table that has mulitiple rows of data for a user.  I want to query that data and return one row for each user.  So I want to take the multiple rows and combine them into one row with multiple columns.  Is this possible?

**Here is what I currently have**

```
UserID   Value
8111     396285
8111     812045789854
8111     Secretary
```

**Here is what I am after**

```
UserID     Column1     Column2        Column3
8111       396285      812045789854   Secretary
```

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: I don't use this enough to be able to give you the syntax off the top of my head. But what you want is the PIVOT command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx Edit: Or maybe it's UNPIVOT, regardless both are covered in that link.

Comment: To expand on Mark Rotteveel's question: is this MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL or some other relational database?

Comment: It would be PIVOT, but that option is only available to him if his RDBMS supports it - MySQL, for example, does not.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: In MS SQL Server `PIVOT` only works if there is a third column whose value can be used as the column in the result set; and the number of columns is fixed (contrary to a similar feature in MS Access for example).

Comment: So I think it might work then.  The table has three columns.  UserID, FieldNo, Value.  I should be able to use the FieldNo as the third column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PIVOT` function to get the result. I used the `row_number()` function to generate the values that will be converted to columns.

If you know how many values you will have ahead of time, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select userid, Col1, Col2, Col3
from
(
  select userid, value,
    'Col'+cast(row_number() over(partition by userid 
                                  order by (select 1)) as varchar(10)) rn
  from yt
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for rn in (Col1, Col2, Col3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a4a4/5).

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Col'+cast(row_number() over(partition by userid 
                                                                                    order by (select 1)) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT userid,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select userid, value,
                  ''Col''+cast(row_number() over(partition by userid 
                                                order by (select 1)) as varchar(10)) rn
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a4a4/9).  Both give the result:

```
| USERID |   COL1 |         COL2 |      COL3 |
----------------------------------------------
|   8111 | 396285 | 812045789854 | Secretary |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot or don't want to use PIVOT/UNPIVOT another option would be to join the columns one by one to the users:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE(
    UserID int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Users (UserID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Users (UserID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @Users (UserID) VALUES (3)

DECLARE @AnyTable TABLE(
    UserID int NOT NULL,
    FieldNo int NOT NULL,
    Value varchar(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @AnyTable (UserID, FieldNo, Value) VALUES (1, 1, 'abc')
INSERT INTO @AnyTable (UserID, FieldNo, Value) VALUES (1, 2, 'def')
INSERT INTO @AnyTable (UserID, FieldNo, Value) VALUES (1, 3, 'ghi')
INSERT INTO @AnyTable (UserID, FieldNo, Value) VALUES (2, 1, '123')
INSERT INTO @AnyTable (UserID, FieldNo, Value) VALUES (2, 3, '789')

SELECT u.UserID,
    col1.Value as Column1,
    col2.Value as Column2,
    col3.Value as Column3
FROM @Users u
LEFT JOIN @AnyTable col1
    ON col1.UserID = u.UserID
    AND col1.FieldNo = 1
LEFT JOIN @AnyTable col2
    ON col2.UserID = u.UserID
    AND col2.FieldNo = 2
LEFT JOIN @AnyTable col3
    ON col3.UserID = u.UserID
    AND col3.FieldNo = 3
```

The result would be:

```
UserID   Column1   Column2   Column3
 1        abc       def       ghi
 2        123       NULL      789
 3        NULL      NULL      NULL
```